# javascript for loop not incrementing using react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using reactjs along with flicity library in my project and just wanted to match the height of the maximun height to all the divs.

Issue : 
its taking the correct value and only appending to the first child not for all. 
Not sure why it is not updating for all the childs.

```js
if (document.querySelector(`.${carousel.styles.trim()}  .flickity-viewport`)) {
  document.querySelector(
    `.${carousel.styles.trim()}  .flickity-viewport`
  ).style.height = maxheight2 + 'px'

  var getCaptionEle = document.querySelectorAll(
    `.${carousel.styles.trim()} .flickity-viewport .mainCardWrapper .caption`
  )
  //debugger;

  for (var cap = 0; cap < getCaptionEle.length; cap++) {
    console.log('0022 --', cap)

    document.querySelector(
      `.${carousel.styles.trim()}  .mainCardWrapper .caption`
    ).style.height = maxCaptionHeight + 'px'
  }
}
```

[image]

HTML :

```
<div class="mainCardWrapper is-selected" style="position: absolute; left: 0%; height: 668px;">
   <div class="animate">
      <div class="relative overflow-hidden lg:pt-100 imgathlete">
         <div>
            <div class="picture"><img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/mtree/image/upload/w_auto,c_limit,q_auto,f_auto/II-SG/6u3pTLmc5AF9HDOm08wRM2/b1e34ae4fa38b75baedc5297a5374b7e/liu.jpg" alt="sdfa"></div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="caption pb-80 py-15 lg:pr-30 lg:pt-23 lg:pb-130 mb-10 relative" style="height: 281px;">
         <div>
            <h3 class="header4 text-darkGrey m-0">Text</h3>
            <div class="eyebrow-small text-darkGrey m-0 inline font-smallcaps">Text Text Text</div>
         </div>
         <div class="mt-15">
            <a class="primary btn px-22 py-12 text-red border border-solid border-red float-left text-12 font-DomainSans tracking-wide relative cursor-pointer event_view_more_details" target="" data-action-detail="e" href="/athletes/">
               <div class="bg-fill w-0 h-full absolute top-0 left-0 bg-red z-1"></div>
               <div class="btn-text-wrapper relative z-10">
                  <span class="btn-txt px-12 eyebrow-small">learn more</span>
                  <div class="btn-arrow-wrapper relative float-right right-0 top-0 w-0 h-12 overflow-hidden mt-3"><span class="btn-arrow"></span></div>
               </div>
            </a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Update :** 
[image]

Comment: Can you share the related HTML?  Also, what is the output of `console.log(getCaptionEle)`?

Comment: currently `cap` variable not used in for-loop. do you need to use this in query selector?

Comment: @Sid : updated pl. check

Comment: It would also help if you could print all variables.  Because it's possible your selectors are not what you expect.

Comment: Can you try converting the HTML node list to an array using `Array.from` ?